# knockout ko.observableArray doesn`t refresh the view

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/k79qc/26/)
When I'm initializing observableArray and call ko.applyBindings it works well. But any other changes to the view model are not displayed on ui. I'm adding another object to observableArray and knockout doesn't render it in the grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you push to an observableArray, you want to call `push` directly on the observableArray itself and not just on the underlying array.

So, you would want to call:

`Categories.push` instead of `Categories().push`.

observableArrays include wrappers to many of the array functions that will perform the operation on the underlying array and notify any subscribers.

Comment: updated the code: http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/k79qc/29/
nothing changed, still not rendering newly added Category. Probably I`m missing aome other thing here.

Comment: It is getting rendered, try increasing the height of your table from 85px to 100px.